# Mariadb not starting after homebrew upgrade

Tags: mariadb, macos-sierra

I upgraded my os x to Sierra and reinstalled my brew list, everthing went well till I reinstalled mariadb.

The database is not starting, i get .ERROR! on mysql.server start

I checked the logs, but i only have two warnings :

```
2016-10-09 10:56:17 140735690990528 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-10-09 10:56:17 140735690990528 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the problem.

Update :

I figured out why the server couldn't start, i had put the service to auto start putting it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` so when i started it i had a log saying:

> mysqld is already running

So i removed the service from the launchAgents but now when I try to start it, i just get :

```
Starting MySQL
...............................................
```

with infinite dots

Update && RESOLVED :

I finally found the solution, the problem here was the mysqladmin not pinging because of a problem in my.cnf so the server started but mysqladmin couldn't ping the server to prompt SUCCESS.

Also my first problem seemed to be a problem in the log-error, i had much logs with different names, i deleted them all and my server works fine now

Comment: How do you start the service? How did u installed MariaDB? Which logs are watching? Put the pth of the log you are watching at.

Comment: I installed mariadb with homebrew and checked the log with
    mysqld --help --verbose | grep 'log-error'
as shown in the mariadb documentation